# Programmatically set protection from accidental deletion on an ou in Microsoft Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have a C# (Visual Studio 2010) application to manage objects in Microsoft Active Directory. When I want to move an organization unit in my application, the software tells me, that I have insufficient priviledges to do that. That's because many objects in our directory are [protected from accidental deletion](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc739350%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Now I would like to check my application if an object is protected. If so, it should deactivate this protection, then move the object to another ou and finally set the protection again.

I've tried

```
// entry is a DirectoryEntry-Object
entry.Properties["ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion"].Value = false;
```

but that gives me an exception.

In Microsoft Powershell you can do it [that way](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd378804%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "*"' | Set-ADOrganizationalUnit -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $true
```

Is it possible to realize this in C#, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add two entries to the ACL for the object:

- Deny Everyone Delete
- Deny Everyone Delete Tree

I just dug up some really old code to do this that should work:

```
Dim currentOU as DirectoryEntry ' This is the object you want to protect
Dim deleteAce As New ActiveDirectoryAccessRule(New NTAccount("Everyone"), ActiveDirectoryRights.Delete, AccessControlType.Deny)
Dim deleteSubtreeAce As New ActiveDirectoryAccessRule(New NTAccount("Everyone"), ActiveDirectoryRights.DeleteTree, AccessControlType.Deny)

Dim currentACL As ActiveDirectorySecurity = currentOU.ObjectSecurity

Dim deleteDeny As Boolean = False
Dim deleteSubtreeDeny As Boolean = False

For Each ace As ActiveDirectoryAccessRule In currentACL.GetAccessRules(True, False, GetType(NTAccount))
    If ace.IdentityReference.Value = "Everyone" Then
        If ace.ActiveDirectoryRights = ActiveDirectoryRights.Delete Then
            deleteDeny = True
        ElseIf ace.ActiveDirectoryRights = ActiveDirectoryRights.DeleteTree Then
            deleteSubtreeDeny = True
        End If
    End If
Next

If Not (deleteDeny AndAlso deleteSubtreeDeny) Then
    currentACL.AddAccessRule(deleteAce)
    currentACL.AddAccessRule(deleteSubtreeAce)

    currentOU.CommitChanges()

    Console.WriteLine("Protected: " & currentOU.Path)
End If
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's the C# code that I use

```
try
{                                
    DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_PATH, DOMAIN_USERNAME, DOMAIN_PASWORD, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

    System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference newOwner = new System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("Everyone").Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier));
    ActiveDirectoryAccessRule rule = new ActiveDirectoryAccessRule(newOwner,ActiveDirectoryRights.Delete | ActiveDirectoryRights.DeleteChild | ActiveDirectoryRights.DeleteTree, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Deny);
    directoryEntry.ObjectSecurity.RemoveAccessRule(rule);

    directoryEntry.CommitChanges();                
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // log the error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The above Code snippets are not really correct. Because to protect an AD object there are two ACEs neccessary. One is "deny Delete + DeleteTree" which must be set on the object to protect, the second one "deny DeleteChild" must be set on the parent object.
If the protection should removed, only the ACE on the object must deleted. The ACE on the parent object must remain, because otherwise other objects in the same OU will not protected anymore!

Here ist my Code which is working perfectly:

```
    //using System.Security.Principal
    //using System.DirectoryServices;

    public static void SetProtectADObject(DirectoryEntry ent, bool Protect = true)
    {
        //get parent object
        var parentEnt = new DirectoryEntry(ent.Parent.Path);

        //refresh objects
        ent.RefreshCache();
        parentEnt.RefreshCache();

        if (Protect)
        {
            #region Protect
            try
            {
                IdentityReference everyOneAccount = new NTAccount("Everyone").Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier)); //S-1-1-0
                var objAce = new ActiveDirectoryAccessRule(everyOneAccount, ActiveDirectoryRights.Delete | ActiveDirectoryRights.DeleteTree, AccessControlType.Deny);
                var parentAce = new ActiveDirectoryAccessRule(everyOneAccount, ActiveDirectoryRights.DeleteChild, AccessControlType.Deny);

                //check if ace present on object
                var objACL = ent.ObjectSecurity;
                bool acePresent = false;
                foreach (ActiveDirectoryAccessRule ace in objACL.GetAccessRules(true, false, typeof(NTAccount)))
                {
                    if (ace.IdentityReference.Value == "Everyone")
                    {
                        if (ace.ActiveDirectoryRights == (ActiveDirectoryRights.DeleteTree | ActiveDirectoryRights.Delete)) { acePresent = true; break; }
                        else if (ace.ActiveDirectoryRights == (ActiveDirectoryRights.DeleteChild | ActiveDirectoryRights.DeleteTree | ActiveDirectoryRights.Delete)) { acePresent = true; break; }
                    }
                }

                if (!acePresent)
                {
                    //set ace to object
                    objACL.AddAccessRule(objAce);

                    //commit changes
                    ent.CommitChanges();
                }

                //check if ace present on parent object
                var parentACL = parentEnt.ObjectSecurity;
                bool parentAcePresent = false;
                foreach (ActiveDirectoryAccessRule ace in parentACL.GetAccessRules(true, false, typeof(NTAccount)))
                {
                    if (ace.IdentityReference.Value == "Everyone")
                    {
                        if (ace.ActiveDirectoryRights == (ActiveDirectoryRights.DeleteChild)) { parentAcePresent = true; break; }
                        else if (ace.ActiveDirectoryRights == (ActiveDirectoryRights.DeleteChild | ActiveDirectoryRights.DeleteTree | ActiveDirectoryRights.Delete)) { parentAcePresent = true; break; }
                    }
                }

                if (!parentAcePresent)
                {
                    //set ace to parent object
                    parentACL.AddAccessRule(parentAce);

                    //commit changes
                    parentEnt.CommitChanges();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Error protecting object {0}", ent.Path), ex);
            }
            #endregion
        }
        else
        {
            #region Unprotect
            //to remove the protection we remove only the ACE from the object, not from the parent. 
            //The ACE on the parent must be in place because otherwise other objects on the same level will not protected anymore!

            try
            {
                IdentityReference everyOneAccount = new NTAccount("Everyone").Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier)); //S - 1 - 1 - 0
                var objAce = new ActiveDirectoryAccessRule(everyOneAccount, ActiveDirectoryRights.Delete | ActiveDirectoryRights.DeleteTree, AccessControlType.Deny);

                //check if ace present on object
                var objACL = ent.ObjectSecurity;
                bool acePresent = false;
                foreach (ActiveDirectoryAccessRule ace in objACL.GetAccessRules(true, false, typeof(NTAccount)))
                {
                    if (ace.IdentityReference.Value == "Everyone")
                    {
                        if (ace.ActiveDirectoryRights == (ActiveDirectoryRights.DeleteTree | ActiveDirectoryRights.Delete)) { acePresent = true; break; }
                        else if (ace.ActiveDirectoryRights == (ActiveDirectoryRights.DeleteChild | ActiveDirectoryRights.DeleteTree | ActiveDirectoryRights.Delete)) { acePresent = true; break; }
                    }
                }

                //set ace to object
                if (acePresent)
                {
                    ent.ObjectSecurity.RemoveAccessRule(objAce);
                    ent.CommitChanges();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Error unprotecting object {0}", ent.Path), ex);
            }
            #endregion 
        }
    }

    public static bool IsADObjectProtected(DirectoryEntry ent)
    {
        //get parent object
        var parentEnt = new DirectoryEntry(ent.Parent.Path);

        //refresh objects
        ent.RefreshCache();
        parentEnt.RefreshCache();

        //get current ACLs
        ActiveDirectorySecurity acl = ent.ObjectSecurity;
        ActiveDirectorySecurity parentAcl = ent.Parent.ObjectSecurity;
        AuthorizationRuleCollection rules = acl.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));
        AuthorizationRuleCollection parentRules = parentAcl.GetAccessRules(true, false, typeof(NTAccount));

        //check object acl
        bool acePresent = false;
        foreach (ActiveDirectoryAccessRule ace in rules)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ace.AccessControlType.ToString());
            if (ace.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Deny)
            {
                if (ace.ActiveDirectoryRights == (ActiveDirectoryRights.DeleteTree | ActiveDirectoryRights.Delete)) { acePresent = true; break; }
                else if (ace.ActiveDirectoryRights == (ActiveDirectoryRights.DeleteChild | ActiveDirectoryRights.DeleteTree | ActiveDirectoryRights.Delete)) { acePresent = true; break; }
            }
        }

        //check parent acl
        bool parentAcePresent = false;
        foreach (ActiveDirectoryAccessRule ace in parentRules)
        {
            if (ace.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Deny)
            {
                if (ace.ActiveDirectoryRights == (ActiveDirectoryRights.DeleteChild)) { parentAcePresent = true; break; }
                else if (ace.ActiveDirectoryRights == (ActiveDirectoryRights.DeleteChild | ActiveDirectoryRights.DeleteTree | ActiveDirectoryRights.Delete)) { parentAcePresent = true; break; }
            }
        }

        return parentAcePresent && acePresent;
    }
```